# How do IPhone apps authenticate with server side technologies?

Tags: iphone

What kind of encryption or hashing is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies if I misinterpreted the question but here goes:

HTTPS is built into the SDK so you can access an encrypted resource using NSURLConnection. As far authenticating you can do it a few ways.

With the NSURLConnection delegate you can implement a challenge / response type authentication process. Full run down on them can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com:80/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009507-SW1). You can also do session and cookie based authentication by building a NSURLRequest:

```
[NSURLRequest setHTTPMethod:HTTP_METHOD_POST];
[NSURLRequest setValue:FORM_ENCODING forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[NSURLRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
```

where post data contains variables to pass for the server side technology to process. I would recommend this way as it is encrypted over HTTPS when sent.

If you require access to cookies you can access them via [NSHTTPCookieStorage](http://developer.apple.com:80/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If you are sending cookies with form data send it with the request:

```
[NSURLRequest setAllHTTPHeaderFields:cookies];
```

Hope that answers your question, if not let me know and I'll try again.

Comment: Thanks Rudiger. You provided me with some good starting points.